# How to crop out the detected mser region in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mser

I am trying to crop out the region detected using mser. The mser.detect() function produces mser-regions and I would like to crop this region to give me the resulting output.I am using python and would really appreciate if someone can help in python.

```
  regions, _ = mser.detectRegions(img)      
  hulls = [cv2.rect(p.reshape(-1, 1, 2)) for p in regions]
  print type(hulls);
  cv2.polylines(vis, hulls, 1, (0, 255, 0))

  #crop_img=[cv2.resize(vis, (b.width, b.height) ,interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) for b in bboxes]
```

I wanted to crop it according to the hulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mask` (in same size with `img`) which has value 1 if its pixel in hulls, others is 0. Then simply use `bitwise_and` to crop the hulls you want.

Comment: I am new to opencv if you can write some code it will really help